# Datetimepicker ability to choose only next 90 days

Tags: datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker installed and like to enable the user to choose only the days within next 90 days (disable all past and > 90 days date to pick). I used maxDate: '+90D' condition, but it doesn't seem to work.

Also, while trying to choose the time, only the past time needs to be disabled. I used minTime: 0, but it disables even tomorrow's time.

Here is the js code which i used:

```
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
inline:true,
minDate: 0,
minTime: 0,
maxDate: '+90D',
format:'d/m/Y H:i',
formatDate:'d/m/Y'
});
```

Here is the link for the jsfiddle: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shanehart3/s7LjL4y3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**use**

```
startDate:"-1d"
endDate: '+90d'
```

**Instead of**

```
maxDate: '+90d'

<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/noonoo/LcqM7/284/">fiddle</a>

  $('#datetimepicker3').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    endDate: "+7d"

  });
```